# How to remove other tabs when one is open

Tags: javascript

So, I have this basic tab module that is supposed to show its respective content once a button is clicked. I have managed to make it open and show content once clicked. However, the other ones stay open as well.

My question is: how do I make it so when one tab is clicked and open, the others hide?

```js
const button = document.querySelectorAll('.tabButton');

button.forEach(function(btn) {
  btn.addEventListener('click', tabClick, false);
})

function tabClick(event) {

  let currentTab = document.querySelectorAll('.active');

  currentTab.forEach(function(tab) {
    tab.className = tab.className.replace('active' , '');
    event.target.parentElement.className += ' active';
    document.getElementById(event.target.href.split('#')[1]).classList.add('on');
  })
};
```

```html
<div class='tabsBox'>
  <div class='tabButtons'>
    <ul>
      <li id='test' class='active'><a class='tabButton' href='#tab1'>Button 1</a></li>
      <li ><a class='tabButton' href='#tab2'>Button 2</a></li>
      <li ><a class='tabButton' href='#tab3'>Button 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class='tabsContent'>
    <div class='tabInner' active id='tab1'>
      <h2>Title</h2> 
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</p>
    </div>
    <div class='tabInner' active id='tab2'>
      <h2>Title</h2> 
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit2</p>
    </div>
    <div class='tabInner' active id='tab3'>
      <h2>Title</h2> 
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit3</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can get a general example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59445099/6525081

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears as though you are using the CSS class `.on` to apply styles so before you set that you could get all the tab content `div`s using `.tabInner` and remove the `.on` class: `document.querySelectorAll('.tabInner').forEach(el => el.classList.remove('on'));`

Your question didn't have any styles included so my code is based on the assumption that the `.on` class is handling display styles.

Below is a working snippet of what I think you are after. I modified parts of your JS code to use `classList` consistently and swapped to arrow functions `() => {}`.

```js
const button = document.querySelectorAll('.tabButton');

button.forEach(btn => btn.addEventListener('click', tabClick, false));

function tabClick(event) {

  const currentTab = document.querySelectorAll('.active');

  currentTab.forEach(tab => {
    tab.classList.remove('active');
    event.target.parentElement.classList.add('active');
    document.querySelectorAll('.tabInner').forEach(el => el.classList.remove('on'));
    document.getElementById(event.target.href.split('#')[1]).classList.add('on');
  })
};
```

```css
.tabInner {
  display: none;
}

.tabInner.on {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class='tabsBox'>
  <div class='tabButtons'>
    <ul>
      <li id='test' class='active'><a class='tabButton' href='#tab1'>Button 1</a></li>
      <li><a class='tabButton' href='#tab2'>Button 2</a></li>
      <li><a class='tabButton' href='#tab3'>Button 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class='tabsContent'>
    <div class='tabInner' active id='tab1'>
      <h2>Title</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</p>
    </div>
    <div class='tabInner' active id='tab2'>
      <h2>Title</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit2</p>
    </div>
    <div class='tabInner' active id='tab3'>
      <h2>Title</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit3</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```